# Ionic route to sibling outlet with id

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular8

I can find advice how to route to a named outlet, and how to route to a sibling route, and how to route with a dynamic id, but I can't figure out how to combine all three things together. Theoretically some version of this should work:

```
this.router.navigate([
        { outlets: { detail: ['result', this.system.id] }}],
        { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent });
```

But I keep getting "Error: Cannot match any routes".

Result module route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: ':id',
    component: SystemResultsPage,
    outlet: 'detail'
}];
```

app-routing.module (lazy loading):

```
  {
    path: 'result',
    loadChildren: './pages/main/system-result-page/system-results.module#SystemResultsPageModule',
  },
```

app.component.html

```
            <ion-router-outlet class="router" slot="start"></ion-router-outlet>
            <ion-router-outlet name="detail" id="detail"></ion-router-outlet>
```

So what I'm trying to do is to link from master outlet to detail outlet. If I change the target outlet to master I get the correct result with the id but to the wrong outlet. If I remove the id I get the results to the correct outlet but without the id I don't have the data.

Comment: Did you try to pass a static id, for example instead of system.id to pass '1', this is to see if the problem is in passing the data or by the variable if there is a problem there!

Comment: Static id wasn't working either.